# In Silverlight : call js function when HtmlPage.IsEnabled == true, Javascript disabled in the browser

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to find a definitive answer to what happens when I call a javascript function from within silverlight with the following conditions:

- HtmlPage.IsEnabled == true
- user has their javascript disabled in the browser

Will the browser just ignore the call?

Will it behave the same for all browsers?

thanks
Michael

Comment: One way to get a definitive answer would be to give it a go and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is itself started by javascript so if it's turned off your application won't be running in the first place, never mind be able to call a javascript function.